Is there any way to use the "My location" feature of Weather.app without Wi-Fi in macOS?
I have a MacBook Pro running macOS 13.6.6 where I frequently turn off Wi-Fi because it has a wired network connection, and I don't want it to try automatically connecting to Wi-Fi networks.
However, whenever Wi-Fi is turned off, the "My Location" feature of the built-in Weather app no longer works, and with it the notification center widget doesn't work either.
The frustrating thing is that if I turn on Wi-Fi but don't connect to any Wi-Fi networks, meaning the only internet connection or IP address is coming from my ethernet connection, "My Location" in Weather.app starts working. So it doesn't actually need a Wi-Fi connection to find my current location, but intentionally breaks its own functionality when one is not available! That's totally daft.
Is there a way to fix this?

I don't use WiFi; I have an Ethernet connection to the cable modem. I set my location in the Weather widget by its 'Edit "Weather"..." menu item. There are options: My Location, and whatever other locations you add. I added my own location, and then selected that one to show. I don't know if this will help you or not. Also, from a different discussion here: in network preferences, drag the Ethernet connection to a higher position than the WiFi connection, to give preference to the hard link. Good luck!

I’ve not seen anyone fool macOS to think it’s getting geolocation without WiFi data being processed through Apple’s OS location services.

Your Mac determines its location using information from local Wi-Fi networks.

Hopefully you can disable auto join and set the network connection priority so you can seamlessly allow WiFi to be on, not connected and sensing local beacons and base stations to look up your location properly.

What I don't understand is how the mac determines its location when the only networks around are encrypted Wi-Fi networks it's not connected to and doesn't have the password for. If it can figure out my location when Wi-Fi is enabled but it's not connected to any network, then why does it need Wi-Fi at all?

My understanding is everyone that opts in on any Apple device feeds distinctive localized observed WiFi identifiers back to a crowd sourced database, @BriBri So every iPhone, iPad, Watch feeds accurate data that all devices without GPS or cellular tower data can be located based on matching past confirmed radio conditions. How precisely this service is implemented is opaque and I haven't seen a proper reverse engineering of it.

For what it is worth, my understanding is that many products - not just Apple's - use the "pinging" of towers, WiFi services, etc. as part of their geolocation services. The device doesn't need to actually connect to the service to know it's location and can use that information to determine the device's location.
Think of it in terms of a GPS navigation system. The Navigation app doesn't actually connect to the satellite, but uses the satellite's identity and direction in 3d space to ascertain the location of the device. Using multiple sources increases the accuracy to the point where modern satellite navigation systems can pinpoint your location to within metres and your speed within a couple kph.
Similar principle for Apple's (and other) geolocation services, but they use the location of sources of WiFi signals and mobile phone towers (both data and phone).
Hope this helps explain how it works.
So the solution is as mentioned elsewhere turn wifi on, but turn off auto-connection to every network. The device will still get the data it needs for geolocation, without connecting to any WiFi network.
Cheers,
